# Spark SQL "Limit"

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, hortonworks-data-platform

Env : spark 1.6 using Hadoop. Hortonworks Data Platform 2.5

I have a table with 10 billion records and I would like to get 300 million records and move them to a temporary table.

```
sqlContext.sql("select ....from my_table limit 300000000").repartition(50)
.write.saveAsTable("temporary_table")
```

I saw that the **Limit** keyword would actually make spark use only one executor!!! This means moving 300 million records to one node and writing it back to Hadoop.
How can I avoid this reduce but still get just 300 million records while having more than one executor. I would like all nodes to write into hadoop.

Can sampling help me with that? If so how?

Comment: does it matter which records? if not then you can use the sample function

Answer (score 8):

Sampling can be used in below ways :-

```
select ....from my_table TABLESAMPLE(.3 PERCENT)
```

or

```
select ....from my_table TABLESAMPLE(30M ROWS)
```

Comment: "Hive also supports limiting input by row count basis ... the row count given by user is applied to each split. So total row count can be vary by number of input splits ... For example, the following query will take the first 10 rows from each input split ... `SELECT * FROM source TABLESAMPLE(10 ROWS);` " https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Sampling

Comment: `TABLESAMPLE(... PERCENT)` is a good solution, ` TABLESAMPLE(... ROWS)` is not. The latter one will use the same `CollectLimit` operation which OP is trying to avoid.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77458260/5142886

my answer from another question, for whom still confused with this.