# (spark sql) Why is it a full table scan for "select id,name from table limit 100"

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hive

Environment:
Spark:1.6.3 and 2.2.1

i have a hive table like:

```
Create table test (id int,name string)
stored as parquet
```

This table contains of 12k files.

Why is spark calculating 12k tasks when i run a limit 100 query like.

```
e.g. spark-shell
scala> sqlContext.sql("SELECT id,name FROM test LIMIT 100").count()
[Stage 8:>                                                     (0 + 8) / 11258]
or
scala>val df2 =sqlContext.sql("SELECT id,name FROM test LIMIT 100")

scala> df2.write.save("/tmp/deleteme/")
[Stage 12:>                                                     (0 + 8) / 11258]
```

Is there a way to prevent this behavior?
Spark2 is a bit different but still like >10k tasks.

I know TABLESAMPLE but i like to understand why spark is acting that way and if there is a setting to change that.

thanks in advance

Comment: how are you reading from the parquet file?

Comment: as i have written nothing more.

Comment: I don't know, but how would spark know in which file it should look at to find 100 entries? Proper databases would have something specific to optimize this (such as the updated sizes of each partition stored in a synchronized place). But I guess spark don't and has to at least plan to read up to 100 entries in each file.

Comment: i thought there is something like it is implemented in hive or impala that it is able to recognize that it parses already 100 rows and removes the other tasks or does not even start them. Even table statistics from impala or hive are ignored. At least with that kind of information spark should be able to do that more efficient.

Comment: You could technically just read the raw parquet files yourself, but yes. It needs to scan all the files before it can know when the row limit is reached. All N executors in Spark must request 100 rows, then 100 of those rows are overall taken. But the solution is actually to avoid using LIMIT altogether. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45887816/2308683 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42512790/spark-sql-limit